# Is this complex function uniformly continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is the function $f(z)=e^{\frac{-1}{z^2}}$ uniformly continuous in the
> domain $0<|z|\leq R, |\text{arg}z|\leq\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ ? Justify.

$f: D\to\mathbb{C}$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)-f(w)|<\epsilon\quad\forall z,w\in D,|z-w|<\delta$.
My attempt:
$\left\vert e^{\frac{-1}{z^2}}-e^{\frac{-1}{w^2}}\right\vert=\left\vert e^{\frac{i^2}{z^2}}-e^{\frac{i^2}{w^2}}\right\vert=\left\vert e^{\frac{i}{z}}-e^{\frac{i}{w}}\right\vert \left\vert e^{\frac{i}{z}}+e^{\frac{i}{w}}\right\vert=\left\vert \cos\dfrac{1}{z}+i\sin\dfrac{1}{z}-\cos\dfrac{1}{w}-i\sin\dfrac{1}{w}\right\vert \left\vert \cos\dfrac{1}{z}+i\sin\dfrac{1}{z}+\cos\dfrac{1}{w}+i\sin\dfrac{1}{w}\right\vert $.

I'm stuck here. I don't know whether it is uniformly continuous or not? Can someone give me any hints to continue?

Comment: I think you can use Heine's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ be the polar form of $z$ and $z=x+iy$, with $x,y \in \mathbb R$. $|f(z)|=e^{(y^{2}-x^{2})r^{-4}}=e^{-\cos (2 \theta)r^{-2}}$. Since $\cos (2\theta)$ is bounded below by a  positive number in your domain it follows that $f(z) \to 0$ as $ z \to 0$. Now use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $0 \le |z|\leq R, |\text{arg}z|\leq\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ (by compatness of this set and continuity of $f$ extended to this set by defining $f(0)$ to be $0$) to finish the proof. [Compactness follows from the fact that the set is closed and bounded].

Comment: I think you don't need the $\varepsilon$-argument. If you set $f(0):=0$ you get a continuous function on the compact set  $D:=\{z: 0\le|z|\le R, |\arg(z)| \le \pi/6\}$.

Comment: You have to prove continuity at $0$ of your fucntion. That is the crux of this problem. Given that $f(\frac  in )\to \infty$ even though $\frac in \to 0$ you have to carefully use the limits on the argument of $z$ in the domain. @Gerd

Comment: But you proved it: $f(z) \to 0$ for $z \to 0, z \in D$.

Comment: I am confused: $i/n \notin D$ since $\arg(i/n)=\pi/2 > \pi/6$.

Comment: Sorry. I thought your $D$ was the open unit disk.  I will correct my answer to make use of your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @geetha290krm why the set above is compact? What are $x,y,r$ in your first line ?

Comment: @AlexNguyen I have edited the answer.

Comment: @geetha290krm I understand why $D$ is bounded. But I still don't get why it is closed? Could u explain for me?

Comment: Use polar form. Supose $r_ne^{i\theta_n} \to z$ where $r \le R$ and $|\theta_n| \le \frac {\pi} 6$. Then $|z|=\lim r_n \le R$.  $\theta_n$ has  a subsequence comverging to some $\theta$ and $|\theta|\le \frac {\pi} 6$.  Can you finish? @AlexNguyen

Comment: why $\theta_n$ has a subsequence comverging to some $\theta$ ?

Comment: $[-\frac {\pi} 6,\frac {\pi} 6]$ is compact.